# Custom ribbon checkbox works in Firefox, not in Internet Explorer

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I'm trying to add a new checkbox in the `Edit link` tab of a rich editor field (in a publishing site). Specifically, in the behavior group.

I set up a new site feature, activated, that contains this element :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="My.Toolbox.RichEditorExtensions"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    >
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.Controls._children">
          <CheckBox Command="MyCheckboxCommand"
                    LabelText="Ouvre le lien en tant que boite de dialogue"
                    Id="My.Toolbox.RichEditorExtensions.MyCheckbox"
                    Sequence="30"
                    Alt="Ouvre le lien en tant que boite de dialogue"
                    TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MyCheckboxCommand"
                          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Custom Script');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Unfortunately, the new checkbox does not appears.

What's wrong and what have I to do to fix this missing checkbox?

**[Edit]** I discover that the checkbon appears in Firefox, but not on IE 9. Maybe a related issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a simple caching issue. Clearing the browser cache solved the issue.